# iOS/core-data: What is best way to check if there is a value for an attribute in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

There are a lot of variants of this question asked but none seem to quite get what I need.

I have an object, contact, which is in a core data entity contacts.  I want to display as much of the address as is present so if there is no zip for example for example, I will leave that out.

I have tried variants of the following without any success:

```
if (self.contact.state && !self.contact.zip) {
NSString *location = contact.state;
}

and also 
self.contactZip.text = self.contact.zip;
if (length(self.contactZip.text)<1) {
NSString *location = contact.state;
}
```

Can anyone suggest right way to do this?

Thx.

Comment: The best way to find out if there's a value is to look up the value and see if it's nil. I'm not sure what you need help with beyond that.

Comment: Evidently the ! is not adequate.  I was able to get it working by testing self.contact.zip.length<1.  Nil did not seem to work as there were cases where there was a value but it was empty as in "".  To confirm, is it the case that nil is different than ""?

Comment: Yes, nil is different than an empty string. An empty string is a value, nil is not a value.

Answer (score 0):

The way to check for the presence of a value with Core Data (as with any Objective-C property) is to check and see if the value is nil:

```
if (self.contact.zip == nil) {
    ...
}
```

Although the `!` syntax is common, it's better to write the code to specifically check for nil [Partly because it makes your code clearer about what it's doing. Partly because `!` is a boolean operator that only happens to work when checking for nil because of implementation details of the language.].

If the property is a string and what you actually want to know is whether it has non-zero length, check both (because a zero-length string is not the same as a nil value). In Objective-C you can take advantage of the language's treatment of nil method calls and do

```
if ([self.contact.zip length] == 0) {
...
}
```

Calling `length` on a nil argument will return zero, so in ObjC this ends up checking both for nil and for zero length at the same time.